# Altering database in onUpgrade get crash

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to add one column in existing table so i wrote the below query in onUpgrade

```
     @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String addMeasureJsonQuery = "ALTER TABLE " + SqlCard.TOOTEET_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + Columns.Tooteet.MEASURE_JSON + " TEXT";
    if (oldVersion == 1 && newVersion == 2){
       db.execSQL(addMeasureJsonQuery);
    }
```

Also updated database version as 2. But my app get crashed with the below error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1516 Process: MyPackageName, PID: 2117
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   tooteets (id TEXT, text TEXT, file_url_1 TEXT, file_url_2 TEXT,
>   thumb_url_1 TEXT, thumb_url_2 TEXT, color TEXT, local_parent_folder
>   TEXT, unique_file_name TEXT, unique_thumbnail_name TEXT, keywords
>   TEXT, created_user_name TEXT, updated_user_name TEXT, is_favorite
>   INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_tooti_author INTEGER DEFAULT 1, tweet_type
>   INTEGER, rating INTEGER DEFAULT 0, weather_type INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
>   latitude DOUBLE DEFAULT 0.0, longitude DOUBLE DEFAULT 0.0, group_key
>   TEXT, tweet_date INTEGER, group_sort_order INTEGER,
>   no_of_unread_tooteets INTEGER DEFAULT 0, no_of_comments INTEGER
>   DEFAULT 0, no_of_unread_comments INTEGER DEFAULT 0, lane_id TEXT,
>   lane_name TEXT, expense_json TEXT, is_synced INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
>   is_update INTEGER DEFAULT 0, is_deleted INTEGER DEFAULT 0) ADD COLUMN
>   measure_json TEXT
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1806)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
>
> at MyPackageName.database.DBSQLite.onUpgrade(DBSQLite.java:80)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:257)
>
> at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>
> at MyPackageName.database.DBSQLite.getDatabase(DBSQLite.java:56)
>
> at MyPackageName.MyApplicationClass$1.run(MyApplicationClass.java:68)
>
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Could you please suggest me an idea to solve this problem? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: ALTER TABLE CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS you are executing wrong command and why you are wrriting on upgrade make a new function for this.

Comment: you are going to change a table if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should directly provide the table name(tooteets) instead of `SqlCard.TOOTEET_TABLE`.Because of this only you are getting Exception near "CREATE"

You can use the following code which i used.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

   // If you need to add a column
   if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
      db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE tooteets ADD COLUMN measure_json TEXT");
   }
}
```